# Excel vba method, "source.copy destination" results in something mysterious

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

This is the macro:

```
Sub dddExport()    
Dim sFile As String    
Dim rSource As Range    
Dim rDest As Range    

Set rSource = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("a1")    

sFile = "C:\dann\dan.xlsx" ''''Adjust as needed    
Workbooks.Open sFile    
Set rDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("a1")    
rSource.Copy rDest    
ActiveWorkbook.Close True    

End Sub
```

no matter what is in range A1, in source, after paste in destination, I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTq5I.png)

```
<TABLE class="table table-bordered" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=1 width="100%" border=1 data-cols="3"><CAPTION style="FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; TEXT-ALIGN: left">Monatsmittelkurs (gültig für Oktober 2019) </CAPTION>

<TBODY>

<TR role=columnheader>

<TH>Land</TH>

<TH>Währung </TH>

<TH>Devisenkurs (Verkauf) </TH></TR></TBODY>

<TBODY>

<TR>

<TD style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold" vAlign=top>Europäische Währungsunion</TD>

<TD style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-ALIGN: right" vAlign=top>1 EUR</TD>

<TD style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-ALIGN: right" vAlign=top>1.1021</TD></TR>

<TR>

<TD style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold" vAlign=top>USA</TD>

<TD style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-ALIGN: right" vAlign=top>1 USD</TD>

<TD style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-ALIGN: right" vAlign=top>0.9983</TD></TR>

<TR>

<TD vAlign=top>Ägypten</TD>

<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" vAlign=top>100 EGP</TD>

<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" vAlign=top>6.0811</TD></TR>

<TR>

<TD vAlign=top>Albanien</TD>

<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" vAlign=top>100 ALL</TD>

<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" vAlign=top>0.9161</TD></TR>

<TR>

<TD vAlign=top>Argentinien</TD>

<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" vAlign=top>1 ARS</TD>

<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" vAlign=top>0.0177</TD></TR>

<TR>....etc
```

if the source is A1:B1, I get in addition also this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"

   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>



<head>

  <title>THIS DOMAIN NAME IS FOR SALE </title>

  <META name="description" content="Contact WebsiteNames.com to inquire about this domain."><META name="keywords" content="WebsiteNames.com, buy domains, for sale, domains for sale, premium domains, webside address, internet address, names for sale">

</head>

<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">

  <frame src="http://www.contactwebsitenames.com" frameborder="0" />

  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />

</frameset>



<!-- pageok -->

<!-- 12 -->

<!-- -->

</html>
```

both files, source&destinaton are new, clean files.
if source range is something else than A1 or B1, nothing happens.
any explanation? (why "Monatsmittelkurs (gültig für Oktober 2019)", why "Contact WebsiteNames.com to inquire" ?)
Thank you.

Comment: *This is the macro* Where it is placed into?

Comment: in personal.xlsb, or as module of the new file.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce - the code provided works without problems (Office 2010 Prof). Try to share problematic workbooks...

Of course none parallel processes which may alter the focus are executed.

Nevertheless I'd recommend to edit your code:

```vba
Sub dddExport()    
Dim sFile As String    
Dim rSource As Range    
Dim rDest As Range    

' Do not use Active???? - use definite object. '
' Set rSource = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("a1") '
Set rSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1")    

sFile = "C:\dann\dan.xlsx" ' Adjust as needed '

' Store the reference to opened workbook - this allows to avoid Active???? usage '
' Workbooks.Open sFile ' 
Dim wDest As Workbook
Set wDest = Workbooks.Open(sFile)

' Do not use Active???? - use definite object. '
' Set rDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("a1") '
Set rDest = wDest.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1")

rSource.Copy rDest    

' Do not use Active???? - use definite object. '
' Use explicit focusing. '
' ActiveWorkbook.Close True '
wDest.Close True
Set wDest = Nothing
ThisWorkbook.Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

End Sub
```